# Comparing a string to a value in the Map<Character, String> and return its' key

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

Good day everyone!

I have a map with keys as characters and their values as strings, it looks as follow (Baconian Cipher):

```
public class MyClass {

private static final Map<Character, String> cipheredAlphabet;
    static {
        cipheredAlphabet = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        cipheredAlphabet.put('a', "AAAAA");
        cipheredAlphabet.put('s', "BAABA");
    }
}
```

I have a string that looks like this:

```
String encodedMessage = "BAABAAAAAA";
```

I want to iterate over it taking 5 letters at a time:

```
StringBuilder decodedMessage = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<encodedMessage.length(); i+=5) {
    String fiveLetters = encodedMessage.substring(i, i+5);
    // compare five letters to values and append the corresponding key

}
```

How I could compare these five letters to values in my map and append to my StringBuilder a corresponding key?

The expecting output:

```
sa
```

Using information from documentation, I came up with something like this:

```
StringBuilder decodedMessage = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<encodedMessage.length(); i+=5) {
        String fiveLetters = encodedMessage.substring(i, i+5);
        // pseudo code starts from this point
        for(Map.Entry<Character, String> entry: cipheredAlphabet.entrySet()) {
            if(cipheredAlphabet.getValue().equals(fiveLetters))
            decodedMessage.append(cipheredAlphabet.getKey());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(Map.Entry<Character, String> entry: cipheredAlphabet.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue().equals(fiveLetters)) {
        ecodedMessage.append(cipheredAlphabet.getKey());
        break;
    }
}
```

But I think it is much better to swap keys and values in you map.

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final Map<String, Character> MAP = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        MAP.put("AAAAA", 'a');
        MAP.put("BAABA", 's');
    }

    public String decode(String msg) {
        if (msg == null || msg.length() % 5 != 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message length should be a multiple of 5");

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i += 5) {
            String letters = msg.substring(i, i + 5);
            Character ch = MAP.get(letters);

            if (ch == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Letters '" + letters + "' not found in local map");

            buf.append(ch);
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it works, even though I had to change to:
    decodedMessage.append(entry.getKey());
when writing:
    decodedMessage.append(cipheredAlphabet.getKey());
the compilation error will pop :)

Comment: Thanks for the opinion and provided example! I will try to play with it around using your way :)

Comment: To do both encoding and decoding you need the `Map` both ways. Or some sort of `BiMap`.